# Создание опроса в чате

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Каким образом можно создать опрос, ограниченный по времени голосования в библиотеке pyTelegramBotAPI, а затем получить количество проголосовавших в опросе и за каждый отдельный вариант?

Answer (score 0):

в общем-то у меня получилось что-то вроде этого. смысл такой. если в чате есть человек, который мешает остальным или нарушает правила, участники вводят команду !мутопрос в ответ на сообщение нарушителя. появляется опрос, и если в нем проголосовало не менее 5 человек и как минимум 70% из них проголосовали за мут, то пользователя мутит на час, а затем опрос останавливается
однако есть проблема. во-первых хандлер ответов не может получить id сообщения с опросом и количество всех проголосовавших. и приходится создавать еще один, который будет этим заниматься. однако он слушает все опросы, а не те, которые связаны с мутом пользователя. ну, и, наконец, последнее - после того, как был создан первый опрос и затем завершен, после создания нового бот не может его завершить

```
elif (message.text == "!мутопрос"):
          #print(message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)
          mutePoll = bot.send_poll(message.chat.id, "Выдать мут этому участнику на 1 час?", ["Да", "Нет"], False, close_date=int(round(time.time() + 120)))
          print(mutePoll.id)
          pollAnswers = [[],[]]
          pollVoteCount = 0
          @bot.poll_handler(func=lambda m: True)
          def voteCounter(votes):
               global pollVoteCount
               pollVoteCount = votes.total_voter_count
          @bot.poll_answer_handler(func=lambda m: True)
          def polls(count):
               global pollVoteCount
               if (len(count.option_ids) > 0):
                    if (count.user.id not in pollAnswers[0]) and (count.user.id not in pollAnswers[1]):
                         if (count.option_ids[0] == 0):
                              pollAnswers[0].append(count.user.id)
                         elif (count.option_ids[0] == 1):
                              pollAnswers[1].append(count.user.id)
               else:
                    if (count.user.id in pollAnswers[0]):
                         pollAnswers[0].remove(count.user.id)
                    elif (count.user.id in pollAnswers[1]):
                         pollAnswers[1].remove(count.user.id)
               if (len(pollAnswers[0]) >= 1):
                    prosent = pollVoteCount / len(pollAnswers[0])
                    if (prosent >= 0.7):
                         bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.from_user.id, time.time() + 3600, False)
                         send_message = "Участник замучен на 1 час!"
                         bot.reply_to(message, send_message)
                         print(1, mutePoll.id)
                         bot.stop_poll(message.chat.id, mutePoll.id)
```